# Access 2013 Calculation with If Statement

Tags: ms-access

Maybe someone can help me. What I am trying to do is to create a calculation with an If Condition. I'm doing my current calculations in the field within my DesignerView.

```
=Summe([Menge/Liter])
=Summe([Menge/Liter]*[Preis/Liter])
```

Here i need to have that it only calculates the tables that have status = 1 
Is there a way how to do this?

Comment: Witch of the two expressions do you need?

Comment: i would need it for both but both are sum and im only using sums

Answer (score 0):

Use [IIf Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php):

```
=IIF(status = 1, Summe([Menge/Liter]*[Preis/Liter]), Summe([Menge/Liter] ))
```

Or is it:

```
=IIF(status = 1, Summe([Menge/Liter]*[Preis/Liter]), "")
```

Comment: i wrote this into the condition generator for my field and im getting that the syntax is wrong it says i gave an operand but no operator

Comment: `=IIF([Status]= 1; Summe([Menge/Liter]*[Preis/Liter]); "")` this way it's not showing any errors but the calculation is still wrong ... i have 3 entry's two with status = 2 one with status = 1 and it calculates all 3

Comment: International versions of Access tend to, sometimes, have different syntax nuances... Stick to syntax and field names in the expression builder. Better to specify if `Status` is a control (`Me.Status`) or Table or Query field (`tableName.Status`). Expression builder helps you there

Comment: this shouldnt be the problem because when i write iif it renames it to WENN thats in my language iif

Comment: That's why I suspect it takes `Status` from the wrong place

Comment: I'm using the [Status] field with the builder

Comment: Try using [FormName]![Status] (or the international equivalent)

Comment: than it opens a window to enter a parameter

Comment: Great! that means you don't have a `Status` field on you form. Do you want one? might it be miss-spelled...?

Comment: i have a status field for sure ... when i'm in the builder i can go to formname than select the fields there i select my field status ... can i possibly that false can't be empty? what should i do as false when it should do nothing .. it's usually " "

Comment: I tested a similar case in my Acc2010: it seems that Access can't (alwase?) base value of a field on another. Try having this code in a form `Current` event: `Me.FieldName =IIF( Me.Status = 1; Sum([Menge/Liter]*[Preis/Liter]); "")`